# Mongodb add a space to field for the whole collection

Tags: mongodb, pymongo

I'm trying to add a simple space `" "` to the end of a string for my whole collection. I'm using mongodb 4.0.0 and can not upgrade, not possible right now. Using this object how can I do that?

```javascript
{
  _id: 'd751b295-6597-4a0b-bd64-89b0fbaac812',
  yada: { type: 'yada', id: 'nkfsh000136' },
  audit: { created_at: '2022-10-03T09:09:22.672144670Z' },
  type: 'yada',
  payload: {
    encounter: {
      provider: {
        first_name: 'yada',
        last_name: 'Doublecheck',
        npi: '1366553539'
      },
      appointment: {
        scheduled: '2022-10-03T09:04:10.588Z',
        start: '2022-09-19T15:04:05Z',
        end: '2022-09-19T15:14:03Z',
        duration: '955'
      },
      codes: { icd10: [ 'R21' ] },
      pharmacy: 'HEB Pharmacy yada#77 (001)'
    }
  },
  vendor: 'yada'
}
```

What I want is this `audit: { created_at: '2022-10-03T09:09:22.672144670Z' }` to look like this:
`audit: { created_at: '2022-10-03T09:09:22.672144670Z ' }`

bonus points, I'll eventually need to remove the space too if you want to help with that.

Comment: If you need to add it for some reason then remove it again, is there something you seek to do in the middle that perhaps is the real issue?

Answer (score -1):

There are 2 ways to do that,

- Create a function where inside the function you will have to get all data first, than do `update`. and it would be better to use [transaction](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/core/transactions/) to handle the query update
- `export` the `collection`, change the data as you expected for and then `import` again

it would be easier to use the 2nd option, and use editor like [vscode](https://code.visualstudio.com/), it would be done in a few seconds.